# Phonegap 3.3 inappbrowser event not fire

Tags: cordova

I already did a search for this problem but seriously they cannot help me out.

I already stuck in this 3,4 days.

I use Visual Studio 2012 , DevExtreme 14.1 and PhoneGap 3.3

I have a button to Sign in by Google Plus like this :

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" onclick="callGoogle()">@LoginWithGooglePlus</button>
```

And then i have a script to do the Authenticate task like this :

```
var googleapi = {
authorize: function (options) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    //Build the OAuth consent page URL
    var authUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?' + $.param({
        client_id: options.client_id,
        redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
        response_type: 'code',
        scope: options.scope

    });

    //Open the OAuth consent page in the InAppBrowser
    var authWindow = window.open(authUrl, '_blank', 'location=yes');


    $(authWindow).on('loadstart', function (e) {
        var url = e.originalEvent.url;
        var code = /\?code=(.+)$/.exec(url);
        var error = /\?error=(.+)$/.exec(url);

        if (code || error) {
            //Always close the browser when match is found
            authWindow.close();
        }

        if (code) {
            //Exchange the authorization code for an access token
            $.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', {
                code: code[1],
                client_id: options.client_id,
                client_secret: options.client_secret,
                redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
                grant_type: 'authorization_code'
            }).done(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);

                //$("#loginStatus").html('Name: ' + data.given_name);
            }).fail(function (response) {
                deferred.reject(response.responseJSON);
            });
        } else if (error) {
            //The user denied access to the app
            deferred.reject({
                error: error[1]
            });
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}
};
var accessToken;
var UserData = null;

function callGoogle() {

//  alert('starting');
googleapi.authorize({
    client_id: '1045340154880-g1givpo92t41f56npo9c2pcos75brop8.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    client_secret: 'Xmfr1uiYru5d6zSGY36nAbuL',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost/oauth2callback',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
}).done(function (data) {
    accessToken = data.access_token;
    // alert(accessToken);
    // $loginStatus.html('Access Token: ' + data.access_token);
    console.log(data.access_token);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    getDataProfile();


});

}
// This function gets data of user.
function getDataProfile() {
var term = null;
//  alert("getting user data="+accessToken);
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + accessToken,
    type: 'GET',
    data: term,
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function (jqXHR, text_status, strError) {
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var item;

        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        // Save the userprofile data in your localStorage.
        localStorage.gmailLogin = "true";
        localStorage.gmailID = data.id;
        localStorage.gmailEmail = data.email;
        localStorage.gmailFirstName = data.given_name;
        localStorage.gmailLastName = data.family_name;
        localStorage.gmailProfilePicture = data.picture;
        localStorage.gmailGender = data.gender;
    }
});
disconnectUser();
}
function disconnectUser() {
var revokeUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' + accessToken;

// Perform an asynchronous GET request.
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: revokeUrl,
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (nullResponse) {
        // Do something now that user is disconnected
        // The response is always undefined.
        accessToken = null;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(nullResponse));
        console.log("-----signed out..!!----" + accessToken);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        // Handle the error
        // console.log(e);
        // You could point users to manually disconnect if unsuccessful
        // https://plus.google.com/apps
    }
});
}
```

The problem is : when i trying to login by Google Plus account, i can logged in, but when they ask me to Agree the App access account information, i click Agree, it will redirect to localhost and say : cannot load like this

(Sorry i cannot add the image)
But this i an url it redirected :

```
http://localhost/oauth2callback?code=4/RlwrXKHntvozNVo-IJNCtA_A-lAI.4nMvnj_fO_UcdJfo-QBMszsQPVcVjgI&authuser=0&num_sessions=1&prompt=consent&session_state=eb1f14e664ff0afed13ae7954898c6a099f3b35a..142d
```

And the Error is : This webpage is not available

I did a research, and i know i get stuck because InAppBrowser events like "loadstart" cannot fire.

Then i try build a native package as Zip, and modify config.xml, add the line

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>
```

, but the result is no change.

Please hint me!

Thank you a lots, any help would be appreciate !

Edited : This is my config.xml after build Native package (Zip)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id=""
    version = "1.0">
    versionCode = "1">
    <name></name>

    <description>DevExtreme based multiplatform application.</description>

    <author href="example.com" email="mail@example.com">PhoneGap User</author>

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.3.0"/>
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>

    <access origin="*"/>

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.file"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.geolocation"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.3.3" /> 

    <icon src="res/PackageIcons.Android.ic_launcher_36_36.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/PackageIcons.Android.ic_launcher_48_48.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/PackageIcons.Android.ic_launcher_72_72.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/PackageIcons.Android.ic_launcher_96_96.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />


    <gap:splash src="res/PackageIcons.Android.splash_200_320.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/PackageIcons.Android.splash_320_480.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/PackageIcons.Android.splash_480_800.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/PackageIcons.Android.splash_720_1280.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
```

Comment: Try with `open` event.

Comment: Thank you for hint me, but...it not work :(

Comment: Did you forgot this `<access origin="*"/>` in your config.xml ?

Comment: Yes i already add this to my config.xml, you can see my config file at the Edited. I only know that i can add more plugin after i build the app as Native Package (zip), not in the Visual Studio, right ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing, config.xml. Now, I am serious doubt with not using addEventListener. So  can you please try with this : `authWindow.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert('start: ' + event.url); });`

Comment: T__T, i have just changed it like this     authWindow.addEventListener('loadstart', function (e) {
            var url = e.originalEvent.url;
            alert('aaaa');  but it not work too, same error appear :(

Comment: Anyone have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. And I figured out that the inappBrowser plugin was missing. Make sure that you install the inAppbrowser plugin . For reference [click here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html).

FYI I installed plugin using cordova cli

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its server auth metod and insted of localhost you should send callback to your server?